# Function inside a for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm a learning javascript. I came across an example in a textbook.

```
function repeat(n, action) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    action(i);    
    }
}

let labels = [];
repeat(5, i => {
        labels.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
});
console.log(labels);
```

For the above example, I'm trying to implement my own code. But the below code is not working.

```
function rep(n){
    
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        i => {
        label.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
       }   
    }    
}
let label = [];
rep(5);
console.log(label)
```

Comment: ``i => { label.push(`Unit ${i + 1}` }`` creates a function. It doesn’t do anything. Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function rep(n){
    
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        
        label.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
        
    }    
}
let label = [];
rep(5);
console.log(label)
```

Answer (score 0):

your i => { } is useless because the for loop do it alone

solution is simple

```
function rep(n){  
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){ 
        label.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
    }    
}
let label = [];
rep(5);
console.log(label)
```

Comment: In first example does `action(i) ` is replaced by `i => { label.push('Unit ${i + 1}'); } `

Comment: yes that's right. Action(i) with this '=>{}' is a lambda expression (if you want to do research on it) ;)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't know about **`arrow function`** or  **`=>`** :
It's a new feature that introduced in ES6 and is called **`arrow function`**. The left part denotes the `input` of a function and the right part the output of that `function`.

So what you did is wrong because you don't need give `label.push(Unit ${i + 1});` input  `i` when you transferred it into the body of your function.

Just change

```
i => {
        label.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
       }
```

to

```
label.push(`Unit ${i + 1}`);
```

and it will works fine.